# T-SQL stored procedure getting same value several times from counter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that is supposed to return a unique number by incrementing a value in a table every time it is called.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextNumber] @Next_Number char(9) output AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @Current_Number int
    SET @Current_Number = (SELECT CONVERT(int, Counter) FROM CounterTable)

    IF(@Current_Number IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @Next_Number = '000000000'
        INSERT INTO CounterTable (Counter) VALUES (@Next_Number)
    END
    ELSE IF(@Current_Number >= 999999999)
    BEGIN
         SET @Next_Number = '000000000'
         UPDATE dbo.CounterTable SET Counter = @Next_Number
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Next_Number = REPLACE(STR(@Current_Number + 1, 9),' ', '0')
        UPDATE dbo.CounterTable SET Counter = @Next_Number
    END

    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Sometimes the stored procedure returns the same number twice. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple processes/threads accessing this procedure?

Comment: Are you invoking this proc in a loop client-side or in another proc?

Comment: What is the frequency of happening?

Comment: Yes the procedure is accessed by a C# component that may run in several instances. But I thought that wouldnt matter when I run the proc in a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this before:

```
update CounterTable set @Next_Number = Counter = Counter + 1
```

which keeps it in a single statement, and so (unless you switch to Read Uncommitted, possibly) shouldn't have issues with multiple callers.

Comment: +1 Most likely this will also be enough to solve OP's problem.

Comment: I actually switched to this implementation as it played more nicely with my C# component.

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly lock the `Countertable` using [Table Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

```
...
SET @Current_Number = (
   SELECT CONVERT(int, Counter) 
   FROM CounterTable WITH(Holdlock, Updlock)
)
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to face such behavior when transaction block is present and moreover the stored proc is being used ? In case multiple users are accessing the same Proc, System will create same number of instances .

Comment: @SQL - The `HoldLock` option is equivalent with `Serializable`. Essentially, you are creating a narrow pipe where only one thread can get through from begin to end.

Comment: I will try this. I am having some problems reproducing the problem since this happened in a production environment when they processed a huge batch. But I still can't understand how this can happen when you do everything in a single transaction?

Comment: @user682728 - it depends on your `transaction isolation level` but using the default level, your `begin transaction` does **not** block other threads from **reading** the counter from CounterTable.